# Execute Javascript function on website using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Is it possible to call a Javascript function on a website that I'm web scraping and saving the result of the function?

I'm using `Requests` to establish a connection and saving certain pages that I need and `BeautifulSoup` to make it readable and accessing certain parts.

There is one part that I'm not sure how to call, or even if it's possible:

```
<tr class=TRDark>
    <td width=100% colspan=3>
        <a href="" onclick="OpenPayPlan('payplan.asp?app=******');return false;">
            Betalingsplan
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This function will open a new window and calculate some data that I need. Is this possible to do with Python?

I cannot use Selenium or similar programs for this. This must be executed in the terminal and only the terminal.

Comment: You can use JSOn parse

Comment: There are no JSON files on the website

Comment: Selenium can use "headless browser" so it can run in terminal.

Comment: check in DevTool in Chrome/Firefox maybe this code send data to servet and get result from server - so you could do the same without JavaScript.

Comment: what page is this? Maybe it has API and python module so you could do it without all JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You need to find a JavaScript interpreter with Python bindings maybe. When you've found one which will fit with your needs you can read the documentation and there you can see how this interpreter works. An example could be pyv8. Python however, does not include a JavaScript interpreter.